# Unmatched closing ')' in replaceFirst

Tags: java, regex

I have this code to remove first closing ')' from an input String:

```
 if (campo.indexOf(")") >= 0){
        campo = campo.replaceFirst(")", "");
    }
```

At runtime, I recieve this error

> Unmatched closing ')'

What's wrong with that replace? I checked that there is a ')' before even trying to replace.

Comment: Might be somewhere in the previous lines, or following lines.

Comment: Please show surrounding code.

Comment: Why bother doing the index check and then the regex replacement? Either unconditionally do the regex replacement, or use the result of the indexOf to construct the string explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should paste the full stack trace...

Anyway, the problem is with this line:

```
campo = campo.replaceFirst(")", "");
```

The first argument of .replaceFirst() is a string literal which is interpreted as a regex, and the closing paren is special in regexes.

You need to escape it:

```
campo = campo.replaceFirst("\\)", "");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try it this way:

```
if (campo.indexOf(")") >= 0){
    campo = campo.replaceFirst("\\)", "");
}
```

`)` is reserved character in regex - and replaceFirst has Regex as first Parameter.

Have a look at [Pattern in JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to see all special characters

And - as pointed out in the comments - the check is not needed. You could simply do

```
campo = campo.replaceFirst("\\)", "");
```

and if there was no `)` in the first place - no replace would happen.